# How to use a javascript to autoplay a html5 audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, hidden

I saw this deface from anonymous, so I want to add a hidden chiptune song when playing the game, but got kinda lost.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ussc.gov/include/js/konami.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var success = function() {
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vKs53Qq5mBI/T9vCsCb-irI/AAAAAAAAB8U/CZsS0iY5RjY/s1600/14685_1_other_wallpapers_anonymous.jpg)";
                document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
                if(window.KICKASSGAME){window.KICKASSGAME.menuManager.menu.messageTypeChangeShip('242,0');
                                       window.KICKASSGAME.menuManager.destroy()}else{
    alert("AntiSec CAEK-mode activated... Destroy the system! Controls: up, down, left, right, space to fire.");
                var KICKASSVERSION='2.0';
                var s = document.createElement('script');
                s.type='text/javascript';document.body.appendChild(s);
                s.src='//hi.kickassapp.com/kickass.js';
                void(0);}
  }

  var konami = new Konami(success);

</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`play` is the method you are looking for

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'YourSong.ogg');
audioElement.load()
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
  audioElement.play(); 
}, true);
```

Comment: Tried to add this snippet between s.src='//hi.kickassapp.com/kickass.js'; and void(0);} with the audio on the root folder but no go

Comment: teh 'load' event didn´t work for me, so I replaced it with the Audio/Video event: `audioElement.addEventListener("canplay", function() {`

Answer (score -1):

Check this out.. It may help you..!

```
function play_sound(url){
    if(play_html5_audio){
        var snd = new Audio(url);
        //code
        snd.play();
    }else{          
        var sound = $("<embed id='sound' type='audio/mpeg' />");
        //code
        $('body').append(sound);
    }
}

play_sound('beep.mp3');
```

Source Code found @ [Automatically playing audio with HTML5 and Javascript](http://jnjnjn.com/187/playing-audio-on-the-ipad-with-html5-and-javascript/)