# chat sound not played in javascript

Tags: javascript, chat

I am facing a problem for playing sound in javascript. The alert box is displayed but the chat sound doesn't play. Following is the code of chat.js.

```
for (x in newMessages) {
    if (newMessages[x] == true) {

    if (chatboxFocus[x] == false) {
        //FIXME: add toggle all or none policy, otherwise it looks funny
        $('#chatbox_'+x+' .chatboxhead').toggleClass('chatboxblink');
        alert('before ');
            var snd = new Audio("facebookchat.mp3");  
             snd.play();
        alert('middle');

        alert('after');
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Get rid of all of the alerts, does the sound play?

Comment: Still after removing the alert i am not getting the sound

Comment: Are you using Firefox?

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you get back the base64 version so I can try again?

Comment: Look in the browser's error console. Are there any errors there? Then look in the console's network tab. Does the mp3 file get loaded correctly?

Comment: is your mp3 located in the same folder as the html/php file that you are viewing?

Comment: base version was 64. and still when i am using facebookchat.mp3, its not working.

Comment: i am using chromium browser and the file is located in the same folder

Comment: You tried using a different audio file/a different browser?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'facebookchat.mp3');
audioElement.load()
audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() { 
  audioElement.play(); 
}, true);
```

Reffered: [How to use a javascript to autoplay a html5 audio tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331929/how-to-use-a-javascript-to-autoplay-a-html5-audio-tag)

It might help, in your case.